# Can't get NInject Conventions working

Tags: ninject

I am struggling to get NInject Conventions to work. I have the following code:

```
public class DataAccessInjectionModule : NInjectModule
{
    var scanner = new AssemblyScanner();
    scanner.From(new[] {
            "Domain.dll",
            "DataAccess.dll"
        });
    scanner.WhereTypeInheritsFrom(typeof(IRepository<>));
    scanner.BindWith<DefaultBindingGenerator>(); // I have also tried new GenericBindingGenerator(typeof(IRepository<>))
    scanner.InRequestScope();

    Kernel.Scan(scanner);
}
```

So basically I am trying to bind interfaces (such as *IFooRepository*) which are in Domain.dll, to the concrete class (such as *FooRepository*) that are in DataAccess.dll.

However, when I later try to fetch the class from the Kernel I get the error:
*No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.*

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `IFooRepository` is not derived from `IRepository<>` but from `IRepository<IFoo>`. If you want to use the interface as condition you have to implement your own condition using Where(t => t.DoSomeReflectionMagicHere()) and do a bit of reflection magic. Another approach is to use the name as the condition e.g. bind all classes having Repository in its name.